# invoking a function polymorphically

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor app has a button which when clicked a specific function needs to be  invoked. There is also a `ActiveTaskCollection` to store `activeTask` field which changes during the app life time.

I am trying to come up with a mechanism to fire the correct function based on the activeTask value without having to write a long conditional statement for every value it could hold.
But only fire the function on the button click event and not reactively when the activeTask changes.

Here is my brain "dump", How can this be implemented? Thanks

```
function a (){console.log{'a'}}
function b (){console.log{'b'}}

activeTask: 'a'
function.call(Col.findOne({last document}).activeTask);  // invokes function a
activeTask: 'b'
function.call(Col.findOne({last document}).activeTask);  // invokes function b
```

Comment: What kind of conditions go into picking the correct function?

Comment: @MikeC The value stored in the field activeTask of the ActiveTaskCollection is the only condition. remember I want to avoid if or switch blocks where a long conditional statement have to be written.:)

Comment: What is `activeTask`? Is it a string, object, number, all of the above?

Comment: @MikeC activeTask is a string as suggested in the code of my post :)

Comment: Guess I missed that haha. In that case, alfthan has a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something in this direction:
Store functions inside an object

```
fCollection = {}
fCollection.a = function(){console.log('a')}
fCollection.b = function(){console.log('b')}
```

retrieve the function

```
fn = fCollection[getActiveTask()]
```

execute the function

```
fn()
```

or in one go

```
fCollection[getActiveTask()]()
```